# Binding a selector to the target of a NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, data-binding

I'm using the following code to add a target binding to a NSButtonCell control:

```
[dataCell bind:@"target" toObject:eventDatesArray withKeyPath:@"selection.self" 
               options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"sellTicket:",              
                                     NSSelectorNameBindingOption, nil]];
```

eventDatesArray is connected by Interface Builder to a NSArrayController. I have established this is done correctly by using the following working code:

```
[dataCell bind:@"title" toObject:eventDatesArray withKeyPath:@"selection.dateTime"
                                                     options:nil];
```

The "selection.self" maps to a specialised NSManagedObject which has a method sellTicket:(NSNumber *)maxTickets. Incidentally, I'm also setting the arguments binding:

```
[dataCell bind:@"argument" toObject:eventsArray withKeyPath:@"selection.venueCapacity"
                                                     options:nil];
```

eventsArray is another NSArrayController.

Where have I gone wrong with the target binding? It simply doesn't trigger the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it appears you need to bind the target and the argument to the NSTableColumn instead of the NSButtonCell.

All sorted.